# No rule to make target 'N', needed by 'certs/x509_revocation_list'

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

I am building the Linux kernel in Ubuntu.  I do this after `sudo make menuconfig`:

> ```
> $ sudo scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS 
> $ sudo make localmodconfig
> ```

and put 'N' for all the options.

Then I tried to do `sudo make bzImage`, but it didn't work, so I did just `make` according to ChatGPT.

It was okay but, I met that code:

> No rule to make target 'N', needed by 'certs/x509_revocation_list'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Note: in general, you should not build the kernel as root.  Use root for system tasks like installing the kernel when you're done.